# center text and icon in a anchor tag

Tags: html, css, web

I'm a beginner at web dev. I want to make a button that has one text and one icon on two separate lines. Since the button is rectangular, I want the text and the icon to be both vertically and horizontally centered to make them look pretty. How should I do about this? 
Thank you.

```css
.typeA {
  width: 80%;
  height: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.typeA span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="btn typeA">
    <span>ABC <br>
       <img src="https://placehold.it/60x60" alt="icon" style="width:60px;">
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Aligning 2 lines of text separated by a <br> is always done by `text-align`, even if you are inside a flex container.

Comment: Pull out your img tag out of span and then you have 2 options, flex or playing around with paddings. There is even a translate solution for vertical alignment. All in all read through this article to get idea https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this simple css to align div vertically and horizontally.

```css
.typeA {
  width: 80%;
  margin:auto;
  height: 90vh;
  align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
.typeA SPAN{
  margin:auto;
text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#" class="btn typeA">
    <span>ABC <br>
       <img src="https://placehold.it/60x60" alt="icon" style="width:60px;">
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the following code

```css
.typeA{
    width: 80%;
    height: 150px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    background:pink;
}

.typeA span{
    display: inline-block;

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="test1.html" class="btn typeA">
    <span>ABC <br>
      <img src=".." alt="icon" style="width:60px;">
    </span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Suggesting you to give a certain height to your button in pixels since your height in percentage won't have any effect to your button

Answer (score 0):

Just this CSS should do it:

```
.typeA {
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    height: 90%;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You should center the content using `text-align`. There is no need for `flex` here, as `flex` actually tries to put several elements on one line.

Answer (score 0):

I used a `button`, and a `<i>` as **fake** icon. The text is in a `span`, so you can style the text via `span` if you want to.

**HTML**

```
<button>
  <i id="fake"></i>
  <span>Click</span>
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
button {
  width: 100px;
}

#fake {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: #ff0000;
  position relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

button span {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 0;
}
```

Hope you can work with it.
If you don't want to use a `button`, I would go the same way like the other answers. Set a `width` and `height` to `<a>` and center the text by `align` and the icon, like explained.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work!

In HTML

```
<a href="">
 <div class="button">
  <img src="file" height="20px" width="20px"/>
  <div>Click me</div>
 </div>
</a>
```

In CSS

```
.button{
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px;
  background-color:#ddd;
  width:100px;
}
a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
```